# Jenkins Git Branch Selection with Fallback

Tags: git, github, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

In my project i have a [GitFlow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) style Repository.

How can I make Jenkins do the following:    (XXXX=Release No)

1. Build the Release-XXXX branch
2. If a release branch does not exist build the Master branch.

I understand I can put branches in priority order using the [git-chooser-alternative](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Chooser+Alternative+Plugin)  plugin but I don't know how to select branches containing the word Release-

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pipeline for this.

```
def doCheckout(cloneUrl,branches) {
 for (String branch : branches) {
  try {
   deleteDir()
   sh 'git config --global credential.helper cache'
   checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: [[name: branch]],
    extensions: [
     [$class: 'CloneOption',
      noTags: false,
      reference: '',
      shallow: true,
      honorRefspec: true],
     [$class: 'WipeWorkspace'],
     [$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']
    ],
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [
     [ credentialsId: 'someCredentialId', url: cloneUrl]
    ]
   ])
   sh "git checkout ${branch}"
   return
  } catch (Throwable throwable) {
   //Try next...
  }
 }
 throw new RuntimeException("Could not find any of the ${branches} from ${cloneUrl}")
}

def branches = ['release','develop','master']
doCheckout(cloneUrl, branches)
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, but I need a solution for a declarative pipeline. Can someone help me please?

Comment: @Hoall can't you use a script block in declarative pipeline?